# PingFederate and Velocity Variable $client_id

Tags: apache, variables, velocity, pingfederate

Variable $client_id is generated at runtime by the server.  It is the Oauth client id from pingfederate.  I am trying to change this variable in my html with a simple velocity if statement like this:

```
<!--Checking for $client_id and setting.  Server setting is Oauthclient1-->
#if($client_id.ne("OauthClient2"))
#set ($client_id = "something")
#end
```

However it will not set, it stays as what is coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which kind of object does `$client_id` contain, but if it's a string, you should rather write:

```
#if($client_id != "OauthClient2")
  #set ($client_id = "something")
#end
```

Or, if it's an object with a `toString()` method:

```
#if("$client_id" != "OauthClient2")
  #set ($client_id = "something")
#end
```

To find out what it does contain if you need so, you can do:

```
<!--Checking for $client_id and setting.  Server setting is Oauthclient1-->
<!-- client_id is a $client_id.class.name -->
```

Maybe you also ought to check if `$client_id` is null or not:

```
#if (!$client_id)
    Error: $client_id is null
#end
```